# Get Props of Globally Registered Components in Vue (v.2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue, If I Import A Component Locally, I Can Have Access to It's Props, Data, Methods & Others.

```js
<script>
import Child from "@components/container/Child.vue";

export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(Child)
  },
```

The Output of The Above Code Is Something Like This:
[image]

As You Can See, I Can Read Component's Props.
But If We Registered This Component Globally, How Wen Can Achieve That?

```js
const Child= () => import("@components/container/Child.vue");
Vue.component("Child", Child);
```

If I Log This, It Has Shown Like This:

[image]

**Update**
My Global Registered Components are Lazy Loading, If I Change Them to Static Import, I Can Read Their Props But Is There Anyway to Read Props of Lazy Loaded Components?

Comment: `() =>` makes it a function, try calling it